# Transform origin on SVG pattern not working on Firefox/Safari

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I made a hexagonal grid with an SVG pattern.

To zoom in, I used transform's scale function, and to keep it scaling from the center I set `transform-origin` to the center of the page.

This is perfectly working on Chrome but not on Safari and Firefox.
How can I make it work on all browsers?

Here's what I made so far:

```js
const pattern = document.getElementById('hexagons');
const center = {
  x: window.innerWidth / 2,
  y: window.innerHeight / 2
};
const transformOrigin = `${center.x}px ${center.y}px`;
let zoom = 1;

const formatPatternTransform = (zoom) => `rotate(90) scale(${zoom})`;

function animate() {
  if (zoom > 3)
    return;

  zoom += .005;
  pattern.setAttribute('patternTransform', formatPatternTransform(zoom));
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

pattern.setAttribute('transform-origin', transformOrigin);
animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  background: #0a0a0a;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<svg ref="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="hexagons"
        ref="pattern"
        width="50"
        height="43.4"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(90)"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
      >
        <polygon
          id="hex"
          points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"
          fill="#0a0a0a"
          stroke="#222"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mosaic" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Your snippet works with my Firefox 77.0.1 (64bits)

Comment: Firefox does not support transform-origin on patterns, only on directly rendered things such as rects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not simply scaling the whole SVG:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  animation:zoom 3s ease-out forwards
}

@keyframes zoom {
  to {
     transform:scale(3);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg ref="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="hexagons"
        ref="pattern"
        width="50"
        height="43.4"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(90)"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
      >
        <polygon
          id="hex"
          points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"
          fill="#0a0a0a"
          stroke="#222"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mosaic" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
  </svg>
```

To avoid the lag you can keep you JS code:

```js
let s = document.querySelector('svg');
let zoom = 1;

function animate() {
  if (zoom > 3)
    return;

  zoom += .005;
  s.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}
```

```html
<svg ref="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="hexagons"
        ref="pattern"
        width="50"
        height="43.4"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(90)"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
      >
        <polygon
          id="hex"
          points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"
          fill="#0a0a0a"
          stroke="#222"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mosaic" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
  </svg>
```

You can easily zoom out too:

```js
let s = document.querySelector('svg');
let zoom = 1;

function animate() {
  if (zoom < 0.2)
    return;

  zoom -= .005;
  s.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position:fixed;
  top:-300%;
  left:-300%;
  width:700%;
  height:700%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}
```

```html
<svg ref="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="hexagons"
        ref="pattern"
        width="50"
        height="43.4"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(90)"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
      >
        <polygon
          id="hex"
          points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"
          fill="#0a0a0a"
          stroke="#222"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mosaic" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: In the example I showed, I only zoom in but actually I also need to zoom out. And the rendering seems a bit laggy.

Comment: @l-portet since it's a pattern you can make the SVG big an zoom out too: https://jsfiddle.net/5oacrbzw/

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative solution. Instead of using `transform-origin` you can center the `<rect id="mosaic"` around the origin of the svg canvas. In this case you will need a viewBox attribute: `viewBox="-250 -250 500 500"` and `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`

```
"xMidYMid (the default) - Force uniform scaling.
Align the midpoint X value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint X value of the viewport.
Align the midpoint Y value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint Y value of the viewport."

"slice - Scale the graphic such that:
aspect ratio is preserved
the entire viewport is covered by the viewBox
the viewBox is scaled down as much as possible, while still meeting the other criteria"
```

And this is the rectangle filled with the pattern:

```
<rect id="mosaic" x="-250" y="-250" width="500" height="500" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
```

Next comes a working example:

```js
const pattern = document.getElementById('hexagons');
const center = {
  x: window.innerWidth / 2,
  y: window.innerHeight / 2
};
//const transformOrigin = `${center.x}px ${center.y}px`;
let zoom = 1;

const formatPatternTransform = (zoom) => `rotate(90) scale(${zoom})`;

function animate() {
  if (zoom > 3)
    return;

  zoom += .005;
  pattern.setAttribute('patternTransform', formatPatternTransform(zoom));
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

//pattern.setAttribute('transform-origin', transformOrigin);
animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  background: #0a0a0a;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<svg ref="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-250 -250 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="hexagons"
        ref="pattern"
        width="50"
        height="43.4"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(90)"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
      >
        <polygon
          id="hex"
          points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"
          fill="#0a0a0a"
          stroke="#222"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
        <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mosaic" x="-250" y="-250" width="500" height="500" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
  </svg>
```